# Put unique constraint on multiple fields of a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I'm working on a ruby on rails app and I want to put constraint on more than one field in database table i.e :

```
|id|field_one|field_two
 1  27        Value
 2  27        Value
```

This should be illegal because combination of field_one and field_two should not repeat. This below is perfectly fine :

```
|id|field_one|field_two
 1  27        Value
 2  28        Value
 3  27        AnotherValue
```

Can I make this constraints at database level? Or I need to do it in my ruby class level?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with a regular validates, uniqueness and scope options:

```
validates :field_one, uniqueness: { scope: [:field_two] }
```

If you want your own custom validation method, you can do this:

```
validates :uniqueness_of_fields

private # optionnal
def uniqueness_of_fields
  if self.class.exists?(field_one: self[:field_one], field_two: self[:field_two])
    self.errors.add(:field_one, "Combination #{self[:field_one]} and #{self[:field_two]} already existings!"
    logger :do_your_thing # here is where you want to log stuff
    return false
  else
    return true # validation passes, is unique
  end
end
```

Comment: Can I log some message if this validation actually occurs?

Comment: Hmmm, what do you mean? This validates implies that it would add an error message on the `:field_one` attribute saying something like "[field_one field_two] are already taken". If you want a custom message  for this validation, tell me so I'll update my answer with an example.

Comment: I'm not doing this in front end, I'm doing this in a job. I want to be able to see that error occurred in the log to catch it if possible

Comment: Wouldn't that be "validates :field_one, uniqueness: { scope: :field_two] }", or validates :field_two, uniqueness: { scope: [:field_one] }"?

Comment: I personnaly name the two fields in my validates. Maybe there is a difference, but I didn't notice it @DavidAldridge

Comment: @MrYoshiji So "validates :field_one, uniqueness: true" checks in the database table for a record having the value of self.field_one. "validates :field_one, uniqueness: {scope: :field_two}" checks for a record having the value of self.field_one where field_two equals :self.field_two. Then, "validates :field_one, uniqueness: {scope: [:field_one, :field_two]}"  checks for an existing record having the value of self.field_one where field_two equals :self.field_two *and* field_one equals :self.field_one. So including both works, but including field_one in the scope is actually redundant.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this as a database constraint. In a migration:

```
add_index :table_name, [:column_name_a, :column_name_b], unique: true
```

Comment: I don't think that a database constraint is appropriate here: You can't see directly in your code why it would not work, the validation would be made on the Database side, which does not provide all the error message system of the Rails framework. Also, to find this constraint, we would have to do some research on the DB system, but with a regular validates, you can directly see the constraint in your Model - where the validation should belong.

Comment: @MrYoshiji. I would agree that a database constraint isn't ideal by itself and at least is better paired with a validation statement. However it can be a useful addition for databases that aren't exclusively accessed by the Rails app.

Comment: Oh you're right, I didn't think of the case(s) when the DB serves multiples applications. Good point ;)

Comment: It could also give the query optimiser useful metadata about the table.